# Error "non-conforming drawing primitive" when trying to draw text or images with graphics magick

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, graphicsmagick

I am migrating a javascript program that internally uses image magick, to a Windows batch file using graphics magick.

I cannot succesfully use the `convert -draw` command.

I have a couple of very simple test cases.The first one is

```
gm convert -size 1920x1080 xc:white -draw 'text 8,8 "Hello, world"' test.jpg
```

fails with the error message "non-conforming drawing primitive (text)".

The other

```
gm convert -size 1920x1080 xc:white -draw 'image over 8,8 0,0 "img.jpg"' test.jpg
```

fails with "non-conforming drawing primitive (image)".

They both fail when invoked from the command line and when invoked from inside a BAT file.

I have tried with and without quotes `"`.

I have tried escaping with `^` the quotes `^"`.

I have tried escaping the single quotes  `^'`.

I am obviously overlooking something very simple, I just cannot see. Any ideas?

**EDIT** Some attempts I made....

```
gm convert -size 1920x1080 xc:white -draw "'text 8,8 Hello'" test.jpg
gm convert -size 1920x1080 xc:white -draw "'text 8,8 \"Hello\"'" test.jpg
gm convert -size 1920x1080 xc:white -draw 'text 8,8 ^"Hello^"' test.jpg
gm convert -size 1920x1080 xc:white -draw "'text 8,8 ""Hello""'" test.jpg
```

but

```
gm convert -size 1920x1080 xc:white -draw "text 8,8 ""Hello"" " test.jpg
```

fails with "unable to read font"

Comment: Have you tried double quotes? -draw "image over 8,8,0,0 ""img.jpg"" " ?

Comment: yes, double quotes, with and without escaping with ^

Comment: ooops... I got a different error message! "unable to read font" ...

Comment: setting all pieces together now it works. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes:  -draw "image over 8,8,0,0 ""img.jpg"" " ?

Comment: Use 8,8 0,0 not "8,8,0,0"