# How to programmatically remove the background of an image making it transparent in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image-processing, imagemagick, rmagick

I have a bunch of images of products and I'd like to remove the background of each programmatically in ruby.  Here are some [example images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6Ba0.jpg) I put up on imgur.

[image]

I'll put an example one here just so you can see but I didn't want to post a bunch of images.  This is the simplest of all of them.  It has just a white background but some of the products have more complex backgrounds.  I know doing something like this on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ7DS.jpg) probably isn't going to work so I'd like to figure that out and  fail gracefully by not actually removing the background and just notifying me somehow.

I'm using ruby on rails 3 and [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) as my upload handler.

Is this even possible or am I only really going to be able to remove white backgrounds?

Comment: If the intended result of this question is an academic discussion about heuristic color analysis, I recommend the answers below. If it's how do you get this job done? Check out the SaaS provider Imagga (http://imagga.com/api/docs/smart-cropping-collage-slicing.html) they offer this exact functionality.

Comment: Google also "Background Burner," which offers a JSON API for removing image backgrounds.

Answer (score 6):

For removing white backgrounds from images, following is a bash script using imagemagick :

```
#!/bin/bash

# pass the image path, image name and threshold(used as a fuzz factor) to the bash script
IMGPATH=$1
IMGNAME=$2
THRESHOLD=$3

# start real
convert ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME} \( +clone -fx 'p{0,0}' \)  -compose Difference  -composite   -modulate 100,0  +matte  ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_difference.png

# remove the black, replace with transparency
convert ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_difference.png -bordercolor white -border 1x1 -matte -fill none -fuzz 7% -draw 'matte 1,1 floodfill' -shave 1x1 ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_removed_black.png
composite  -compose Dst_Over -tile pattern:checkerboard ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_removed_black.png ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_removed_black_check.png

# create the matte 
convert ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_removed_black.png -channel matte -separate  +matte ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_matte.png

# negate the colors
convert ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_matte.png -negate -blur 0x1 ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_matte-negated.png

# eroding matte(to remove remaining white border pixels from clipped foreground)
convert ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_matte.png -morphology Erode Diamond ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_erode_matte.png

# you are going for: white interior, black exterior
composite -compose CopyOpacity ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_erode_matte.png ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME} ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_finished.png

#remove white border pixels
convert ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_finished.png -bordercolor white -border 1x1 -matte -fill none -fuzz  ${THRESHOLD}% -draw 'matte 1,1 floodfill' -shave 1x1 ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_final.png

#deleting extra files
rm ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_difference.png
rm ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_removed_black.png
rm ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_removed_black_check.png
rm ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_matte.png
rm ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_matte-negated.png
rm ${IMGPATH}${IMGNAME}_finished.png
```

I was facing a problem removing white border pixels from the resulting image. Eroding the binary mask  and shaving the remaining pixels solves the problem.

---

Source : [convert white to transparent](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/12/convert-white-to-transparent.html)

Comment: This looks really promising solving the issue I have. However, I run into the following problem when trying to use this script. 'non-conforming drawing primitive definition `matte' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3269'. Any idea what could cause this? Using Mac and ImageMagick 7.0.5-0 Q16 x86_64

Comment: Try double checking your single/double quotes.
See if this answer helps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8701126/2175224

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I tried that, but did not work and was not the issue. However, I read somewhere that the syntax for this script is pretty old, and matte seems to be replaced by alpha(?). So when I changed 'matte 1,1 floodfill' to 'alpha 1,1 floodfill' it worked! Thanks a lot for the script, works like a charm after some tweaking for my use case!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#bg_remove

You can probably do fairly well with solid-color backgrounds, but non-solid backgrounds (like the one in the image that you linked to) are fairly difficult, and I doubt that you'll be able to come up with a single method that will work for all images.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick is the most likely solution here (perhaps with the mini-magick gem for rails), but as you suggest, it's unlikely you'll have a good result in some cases.  Simply turning all white pixels into transparent will most likely leave ragged edges that will be quite apparent on a non-white background.  But there are a surprising number of options that give you a lot of the kind of control you might have in PhotoShop or other -- you'll create a mask that finds  the outline of shape within a certain tolerance of hue, color or the like, than changing all matching pixels to transparent.  I think you'll also have to change to PNG format, as I don't believe JPEG supports alpha-transparency.

CarrierWave is the right tool for this kind of processing -- you might use its "versions" capabilities to store the original file, and make a few automated attempts using different parameters (which will save different files without touching the original).

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#two_background might give you a start.

Comment: What about detecting if an image will work or not?  That is my other concern.  I don't want to do it on an image that will fail spectacularly.

Comment: Without a known set of images (i.e. all have white backgrounds), the problem, while likely possible to do isn't worth the effort -- a human could pick the best option in a moment.  So consider using Amazon Mechanical Turk, which has an API, to present the image versions to actual humans, letting them select the best option.  Check out MTurk -- it's brilliant for this kind of problem.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you mean to batch process a bunch of unrelated files. To my understanding you can't as removing the background (by pulling a matte) is a severely underconstrained problem and necessarily requires user input. A constant background colour like a blue or green screen will free you to do a pretty good job with free programmes such as gimp but nothing can do a great job unless you want to read bleeding edge scientific journals on a for instance

Poisson Matting

http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=69117

OR

A closed form solution to natural image matting

www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~levina/papers/Matting-Levin-Lischinski-Weiss-CVPR06.pdf

The later has matlab code provided for academic purposes. But these are all serious number crunchers and can use all your system resources on larger files as can be ascertained from the trial version pullmatt application from http://PixelFeather.com/download. Which by the way does the best job for the natural image problem of any proprietary software including photoshop.

Comment: While this is a good answer as to which programs to use for the job - the question prompts how to do it *programmatically*; your answer, unfortunately, doesn't provide that.

Comment: Yes fair comment. When I read the original post I don't think hadees was necessarily intending to batch process a series of unrelated images and in fact finished by asking if it could be done with only white background images. i.e. images related by their white backgrounds. Also batch processing was clearly an assumption of mine and was not even mentioned. I was intimating that for unrelated images batch processing would be very very difficult (impossible).