# How do I deal with non-conforming drawing primitive definition error when trying to draw text that contains spacing?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Given a text file, the following script is meant to draw text:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo "Name of the text file?"
read tf
echo "Width?"
read wi
echo "Height?"
read hi
echo "Fill (font) color?"
read fc
echo "Background color?"
read bc
  
convert -size "${wi}x${hi}" xc:"${bc}" -font Helvetica \
-pointsize 24 \
-fill "${fc}" \
-gravity center \
-draw "text 0,0 $(cat ${tf})" \
image.png
```

This script works fine if the text in the file does not have spacing in it.
Spacing is an issue, e.g. when the file contains `I love you so much` I get the following error: `` convert-im6.q16: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `love' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4404. ``
[Using double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700074/error-non-conforming-drawing-primitive-when-trying-to-draw-text-or-images-with) around the text has not solved the matter.

Environment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, `Version: ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25`.
[Using double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700074/error-non-conforming-drawing-primitive-when-trying-to-draw-text-or-images-with) around the text has not solved the matter.

Comment: Why do you need the "cat". If tf is a variable, you can use it directly in the -draw as `-draw "text 0,0 '$tf'"`

Comment: @fmw42  I think `tf` is a filename rather than a string containing text.

Comment: If tf is a filename.suffix (current directory) or path to a file, then `-draw "text 0,0 '@tf'"` Provided your policy.xml file gives permission for the use of @ syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need double quotes around the text you want to draw... but your string is already in double quotes, so you need to escape them:

```
#!/bin/bash

wi=640
hi=480
bc="red"
fc="white"
tf="stuff.txt"
convert -size "${wi}x${hi}" xc:"${bc}" -font Helvetica \
-pointsize 24 \
-fill "${fc}" \
-gravity center \
-draw "text 0,0 \"$(cat ${tf})\"" \
image.png
```

[image]

Just to clarify, the syntax is:

```
convert ... -draw "text 0,0 'Some text surrounded by quotes'" ...
```

but as you want the text from a file expanded and placed into the command, you cannot use single quotes because they don't allow interpolation (or expansion of variables), so you need escaped double quotes instead.

---

Or you can use `label:` and allow **ImageMagick** to choose the largest font that will fit:

```
#!/bin/bash

wi=640
hi=480
bc="red"
fc="white"
tf="stuff.txt"
convert -size "${wi}x${hi}" -background "${bc}" -font Helvetica \
-gravity center \
-fill "${fc}" \
label:@"$tf" \
image.png
```

[image]

---

My file `stuff.txt` looks like this:

```
A message with spaces in it.
```